# How to make image placeholder?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, placeholder

How to get image placeholder? It should looks like empty place (16*16) in gray color.
And when i select image- it places into placeholder.

I know how to select image from files, but i do not know how to make empty space (16*16 with gray color).

Can you get me some links or simple example?
Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you make such an image and use it as a placeholder and then replace it with the selected image?

Comment: Could also be easily generated on the fly with a `var pImage = new Bitmap(16,16);`, acquiring a `Graphics pGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(pImage)` object on it and calling `pGraphics.Clear(Color.Grey)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something as simple as:

```
<Grid Background="Gray">
   <Image />
</Grid>
```

When image loads, it will cover the gray color.